# Nested joins on rails doesn't seems to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

So, the thing goes this way:

**Relations:**

Type has many Programs,
Program belongs to a Types

Programs has many Groups,
Group belongs to Program

Type model:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :programs
end
```

Program model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :type
    has_many :groups
end
```

Group model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
end
```

**On my view:**

```
<% @Types.each do |type|%> //this works
   //Print some info about type

  <%type.programs.each do |program|%> //this also works
     //Print some info about this program, which depends of the type above

     <%program.groups.each do |group|%> //this doesnt work at all
         //Print some info about this group, which depends of the program above
     <%end%>    

  <%end%>

<%end%>
```

The error I get is the following one:

```
uninitialized constant Program::Groups
```

and the app trace is:

```
app/views/admin/index.html.erb:33:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_admin_index_html_erb__4501256709281346516_69833887896820'
app/views/admin/index.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_admin_index_html_erb__4501256709281346516_69833887896820'
app/views/admin/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_admin_index_html_erb__4501256709281346516_69833887896820'
```

Comment: Try program.groups  instead of program.group

Comment: Which line in your `index.html.erb` has number of 33? Also, edit your view code to fix `group` typo.

Comment: <%program.group.each do |group|%>, the one that says "//this doesnt work at all" n_n

Comment: So you have `<% program.group.each do |group| %>` in this line, right?

Comment: yes, exactly, that one

Comment: Modify it to `groups` then.

Comment: Now, what if you specify class name in your association explicitely? (`has_many :groups, class_name: 'Group'`)? If it works, did you override your inflection rules?

Comment: As I said, that was yust a typo error, I wrote right on my project, and already modified in the question :P

Comment: At last. Duplicating this typo was pretty misleading and annoying.

Comment: yea, sorry for that. I use your advice and it works, why this happens?

Comment: Go to your `rails console` and check what does `'groups'.singularize` return. It may be connected with overriden inflector rules.

Comment: `'groups'.singularize`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Program` model

```
has_many :groups
```

In your view it should be

```
program.groups.each do
```

you missed the 's' in groups

Comment: @wcsantos if so, edit your question respectively. And add the code of `Program` model.